# bootstrap modal.js last complete button missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm just trying to learn modal.js I'm expecting that at the last page(data-step=3), I would see a finish button and when i click on that, it'll close the modal. But the problem here is, at the last page, only the cancel and previous button is visible. The next button is hidden, which is fine but i thought it would be replaced by the finish button. What am i missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>WhyQ</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,400italic,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-o.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='tab-shopping-cart'  class="order-nav-tab" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cartModal">
    <div class="order-nav-shopping-cart">Click here</div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="cartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cartModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-cart modal-dialog-cart">
        <div class="modal-content modal-cart modal-content-cart">
            <div class="modal-body modal-cart" style="overflow:scroll">
                <div class="row hide cart-s1-common" data-step="1" id="modal-step-1">
                    <div class="row modal-header modal-header-cart" >
                        <div class="modal-shopping-cart"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cart-s1-title">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 txt-center">
                            ORDER
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 txt-center">
                            PRICE
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 txt-center">
                            QTY
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 txt-center">
                            TOTAL
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </div>

                <div class="row hide cart-s2-common" data-step="2">
                    <div class="row cart-s2-title">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 txt-center">
                            TIME REMAINING:<br/>
                            <label id="lblCountDown"></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row cart-s2-content">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 txt-center">
                            <div class="row">
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='10:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='11:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='12:00'/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='13:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='14:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='15:00'/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='16:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='17:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='18:00'/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='19:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='20:00'/>
                                <input id='cart-s2-timepicker' type='button' class='cart-s2-timepicker' value='21:00'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row hide cart-s3-common" data-step="3">
                    This is the last step!!!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer modal-footer-cart">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-cart js-btn-step pull-left" data-orientation="cancel" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-cart js-btn-step" data-orientation="previous"></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-cart btn-success js-btn-step" data-orientation="next"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#cartModal').modalSteps({
    btnCancelHtml: 'Quit',
    btnPreviousHtml: 'Back',
    btnNextHtml: 'Go',
    btnLastStepHtml: 'Finish'
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of the three buttons in the `.modal-footer-cart` is the first supposed to be the cancel button? It doesn't have any text...

Comment: Yes, the first is cancel, second is previous and the last is next. I've already specified the text in the jquery statement at the last script block

Comment: Are you using a plugin for bootstrap? What is `.modalSteps`?

Comment: yes it is a plugin. Its called bootstrap steps plugin. Is that not a common plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

1. Order your includes in header - jquery, bootstrap css + other css files, bootstrap.js, respond.js then jquery-bootstrap-modal-steps.js (as I see from your code this one is missing) and your specific page scripts. It should look like this.

   ```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>WhyQ</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,400italic,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style-o.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-bootstrap-modal-steps.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
   ```

   2. You can use only `$('#myModal').modalSteps();` and test if it works correctly then start adding Available options and callbacks.

for more info check this => 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Create-Step-By-Step-Modal-with-jQuery-Bootstrap.html

Comment: Hi, turns out my colleague commented the Complete button in the modalStep.js file. That's why its not showing up. Thanks for the help anyways.